# trigger click event for button located in previous page

Tags: javascript, html, web, events, click

I am a beginner developing a web application when history.back() is called I want to programatically click a button in the previous page.
I have 2 pages page1 and page2, when history.back is called from page2 I would like to go back to page1 and click end button that is present in page1

```
    document.addEventListener("start", () => {
        console.log("session ended");
        console.log("final", Content);
        history.back();
        document.querySelector(".end__button").click();
    });
```

```
            <div class='end__button'>
                <button>btn</button>
            </div>
```

query selector either cannot find button or line is not executed.
How can I solve this problem? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to keep track of when you need to click the end button that is in page 1 when you load the page.

page 1:

```
if(Boolean(window.sessionStorage.getItem('end'))) //click end button

window.sessionStorage.setItem('end', false); //reset
```

I am using `Boolean()` here to turn `end` into a boolean (so that `"false"` won't be truthy), since sessionStorage turns values into strings. You can see this if you tried:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('number', 0);
window.sessionStorage.setItem('boolean', true);

typeof window.sessionStorage.getItem('number'); //string
typeof window.sessionStorage.getItem('boolean'); //string
```

You could also try `if(window.sessionStorage.getItem('end') === 'true')` as well.

page 2:

```
document.addEventListener('start', () => {
  //do stuff
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('end', true);
  history.back();
});
```

Make sure you `setItem` **before** you call `history.back()`.

Comment: it didn't work, also isn't if condition executed only once?

Comment: For the second question, everything runs again when you load a new page

Comment: You are trying to click the div, not the button inside the div. Try doing ``document.querySelector(".end__button button").click();`` This selects all the first button that is a child of ``.end__button``.

Comment: regarding document.querySelector(".end__button button").click(); this is what I've been using,

Comment: it only worked when I added an event listener 'load', but page isn't reloaded with history.back(), any suggestions?